# Can't do a cumulative sum with legends in a stacked chart (Power Bi)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to Power Bi. My manager asked me to illustrate the growth of the company with a stacked chart.

All is fine when i don't add legends to it (the different stores). But when i do this happens :

[Broken chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ree.jpg)

I want the orange part (Omega company) to also appear in 2022.(even though they made no benefits for that year)

What measure do I need to make this happen ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's a simplified caption of what the excel file for the power bi report looks like.

Thank you !!

[Excel sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DvM1.jpg)

Comment: if there is no benefit data for 2022, how do you expect PBI to show it on the chart ?

Comment: Try other charts with your data.

Comment: The question is about the "cumulative sum" and of cause this has numbers in 2022, even if nothing is added in that year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Quick measure` "Running Total" to achieve that, but you need a separate "Dates" table that you can build as a calculated table via

```
Dates = GROUPBY('Table','Table'[Date])
```

and that you need to relate 1-to-many to your original table.

[image]

Now in the `Quick measures` UI for "Running total" you set the `Base value` to "Sum of Benefits" and the `Field` to "Date - Year"

[image]

With that measure "Benefits running total in Year" and your Excel sample data from above your Stacked column chart looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Your method worked like a charm. I had set up a date table, but I completely forgot to link it up to the facts table.I have my date table set until 2024. Is there any way of getting the results only until "today'. Or do i have to return to the chart and filter it every year ?

Answer (score 0):

What does your measure look like?

If you have a relationship between your fact table and date dimension table, you can try something like this

```
Running Total Benefits =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Fact Table'[Benefits] ),
    ALL ( 'Date Table' ),
    'Date Table'[Date] <= EARLIER ( 'Date Table'[Date] )
)
```

Or use DATESBETWEEN function if they don't have relationship

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried your formula and i'm getting this message : "Earlier refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist". I used this formula for the measure :

CALCULATE(
 SUM('facts'[Benefits]),
 FILTER(
  ALLSELECTED('Dates'[Date]),
  ISONORAFTER('Dates'[Date], MAX('Dates'[Date]), DESC)
 )
)